# Get request on Heroku returns create-react-app default page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I have a heroku backend in which I'm trying to retrieve data from: https://jabooda-homes-backend.herokuapp.com/

When I serve this app locally, I'm successfully able to retrieve this data; however, when I do a GET request to the Heroku app via Postman, I notice that the React default HTML page gets sent back. Here's an image demonstrating this:

[image]

Here's a snippet of the backend code that gets the data:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

// Routes
app.use('/api', router)

router.get('/getCareerData', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
    console.log('***************************************************************************************************************************************')
    console.log(res)
    var data = res.json({
            success: true,
            data: {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5c200d53e7179a74879741fb"
                },
                "jobtitle": "FRAMER",
                "description": "",
                "requirements": [
                    "Measure, cut and assemble lumber with precision",
                    "Be able to lift and carry heavy framing lumber, sheets of plywood and other materials",
                    "Strong analytical and mathematical skills"
                ],
                "updatedAt": {
                    "$date": "2019-02-06T22:04:42.721Z"
                }
            }
    })

    return data
    // return retrieveData(Careers, req, res)
})
```

(Note: I have the BE linked to MongoDB, which gets data from there; however for testing purposes I'm just trying to return the data variable I created).

Again, when I run a localhost the data comes back just fine; however when I try to do this via Heroku, it fails. Does anyone know how to bypass this? Am I not uploading my app to Heroku correctly? I have CORS set up on my Frontend, but I'm wondering if there's extra configurations that I need to set up in order to get this data through Heroku. Any feedback would be appreciated, and if there's more info you'd like me to include, please let me know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -- My back end was a react app from create-react-app, and I just removed everything associated with react on the back end app... now it works!